# Jetty9 does not load properties from Java properties file

Tags: properties-file, jetty-9

The Jetty documentation says:

> **Property Files**
>
> Standard Java property files are also used for Jetty
>   configuration in several ways:
>
> - To parameterize Jetty IoC XML via the use of the Property element.
> - To configure the default logging mechanism (StdErrLog). Other logging
>     frameworks can be utilized and also use property files (for example,
>     log4j).
> - As a simple database for login usernames and credentials.

I'm trying to achieve the first point: parameterizing my jetty-env.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_3.dtd">

<Configure id='wac' class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <New id="oracleDS" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
    <Arg>
      <Ref refid='wac'/>
    </Arg>
    <Arg>jdbc/oracleDB</Arg>
    <Arg>
      <Call class="oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceFactory" name="getPoolDataSource">
        <Set name="URL"><SystemProperty name="database.url" /></Set>
        <Set name="user"><SystemProperty name="database.user" /></Set>
        <Set name="password"><SystemProperty name="database.password" /></Set>

        <Set name="connectionFactoryClassName">oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource</Set>
      </Call>
    </Arg>
  </New>
</Configure>
```

So the basic question is, how can I achieve that my Java `*.properties` file, which I placed under `${jetty.base}/resources` directory (after enabling the resources module), gets accessible as Property or SystemProperty?

Initially I thought placing it in the resources folder would be enough, since the documentation of the module says

> Module: resources
>
> Adds the $JETTY_HOME/resources and/or $JETTY_BASE/resources
>   directory to the server classpath. Useful for configuration
>   property files (eg jetty-logging.properties)

Then I've tried to reference the file within the `start.ini` which also did not work out.

As a last try I handled the file name as an argument during the startup of Jetty: `java -jar start.jar resources\my.properties`

In all cases no error is shown, but calling `java -jar start.jar --list-config` does not show the entries as expected, nor I'm able to access the Property directly from my Java code: `System.getProperty("propertyKey")`

If I pass the properties directly as a jvm option (`java -jar start.jar -DpropertyKey=propertyValue`), which is no option for production, it works just fine.

**Update 16.6.:** Integrating the properties in the `start.ini` is not really an option, because the application need to be automatically deployed in different environments with different connection settings. This is much easier done with a seperate config file, which only includes the database connection settings outside the *.war and any other configuration file.

What is my best option here?

Answer (score 2):

> Note: do not edit/change/delete/rename/modify any content in your `${jetty.home}` directory. 
>   (`${jetty.home}` is the location where you unpacked 
>   `jetty-home-<ver>.tar.gz` or `jetty-distribution-<ver>.tar.gz`)

In your `${jetty.base}/start.ini` just list them.

aka

```
-Ddatabase.url=db://foo/table
-Ddatabase.user=admin
-Ddatabase.password=secret
```

That puts them on the System.getProperties() list.

Using `<SystemProperty name="key"/>` is sufficient to get access to them in the XML.

Comment: I thought about this option but, integrating these information in a file with other content makes it more difficult to use automatic deployment for different environments. That's why I would prefer to write the properties in a seperate file.

Comment: Then call it `${jetty.base}/start.d/mydb.ini`, same thing.

Comment: Or use the tiered configurations `${jetty.home}` -> `/myenv/start.ini` -> `${jetty.base}` to accomplish this on a env specific scenario.